# R - Computations with lag variable by group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lag

Using the following dataset:

```
set.seed(2)
origin <- rep(c("DEU", "GBR", "ITA", "NLD", "CAN", "MEX", "USA", "CHN", "JPN", "KOR","DEU", "GBR", "ITA", "NLD", "CAN", "MEX", "USA", "CHN", "JPN", "KOR"), 6)
dest <- rep(c("GBR", "ITA", "NLD", "CAN", "MEX", "USA", "CHN", "JPN", "KOR","DEU", "GBR", "ITA", "NLD", "CAN", "MEX", "USA", "CHN", "JPN", "KOR", "DEU"), 6)
year <- rep(c(rep(1998, 10), rep(1999, 10), rep(2000, 10)), 2)
type <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 12)
# type <- sample(1:10, size=length(origin), replace=TRUE)
a <- sample(100:10000, size=length(origin), replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1000:100000, size=length(origin), replace=TRUE)
data.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(origin, dest, year, type, a,b))
rm(origin, year, dest, type, a,b)
```

I would like to compute, for instance, the following operation:

- [a  <sup>t+1</sup>   <sub>ijk</sub>  - a  <sup>t</sup>   <sub>ijk</sub> ] * b  <sup>t</sup>   <sub>ik</sub>

i being `type`, j `origin` and k `dest`. I decided to first compute the lag of a, `lag.a` with `dplyr`:

```
data.df <- data.df %>%
            group_by(origin, dest, type) %>%
            mutate(lag.a = lag(a, n = 1, default = NA))
```

I think this way is correct even if I do not understand well how R can understand alone what is the time reference to consider... ??

Btw, doing so I obtained a result corresponding to the first part (a  <sup>t+1</sup>   <sub>ijk</sub>  - a  <sup>t</sup>   <sub>ijk</sub> ) of my computation. My problem is that I now I no idea of how i can do (lag.a  <sup>t+1</sup>   <sub>ijk</sub>  * b  <sup>t</sup>   <sub>ik</sub> )... Any idea?

If possible I would like a solution (`dplyr` or `data.table`), with no mutate of the lag variable into the dataset to not weigh it down more than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code. First, create your `data.frame` like this:

```r
data.df <- data.frame(origin, dest, year, type, a, b)
```

This will retain the class of all the vectors. Note that if you don't want `origin` and `dest` to be factors, just use the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame()` function.

Next, create your new variable as follows:

```r
data.df2 <- data.df %>%
  group_by(origin, dest, type) %>%
    arrange(year) %>% 
    mutate(new_var = (a - lag(a)) * b) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here, `new_var` is the variable that you want. You are right in that `dplyr` doesn't know that the lagged value is from the previous time period. Therefore, you have to use `arrange(year)`.

Comment: origin and dest are a finite  list of countries (around 180) in my dataset. It can therefore be as a categorical variable, can't it? Why do you think it is useful to "unstringAsFactors" ?

Comment: That's up to you. It doesn't change anything. I just wrote that you can not have them as factors by using that argument. Did my solution solve your problem?